# Reuse existing iOS simulators in updated Xcode 15.0.1

Tags: ios, mac, xcode, xcode-simulator

I updated to Xcode v15.0.1 and now its downloading the simulators again.

Is there any way to reuse the existing simulators that were downloaded in Xcode v15?

Edit: I still have Xcode 15 in my macbook and its not deleted.